# Error TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am a new laravel. I try to create category into the database but i meet the problem of TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:. After meet this problem i try to add {{ csrf_field() }} into my form but it got the same error. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

**View Form**

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => ['Page_Admin@updatemaincate', $main_cate->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-date')); !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3C8DBC;">
        <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#fff;">New Main-Category</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">                               
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title'); !!}
                        {!! Form::text('title', $value = $main_cate->title, $attributes = ['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'title']); !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!--end 12-->
        </div> <!--end row-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer custom-default">
        {!! Form::submit('Edit', $attributes = ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close(); !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function maincategories()
{
    $maincategory = maincategory::all();
    return view('admin/maincategories', compact('maincategory'));
}

public function setmaincate(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);

    $tbl_maincate = new maincategory;
    $tbl_maincate->title = Input::get('title');
    $tbl_maincate->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Adding multiple images are successfully');
    return Redirect('/maincategories');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', 'Page_Admin@index');
Route::resource('admin', 'Page_Admin');
Route::get('maincategories', 'Page_Admin@maincategories');
Route::post('setmaincate', 'Page_Admin@setmaincate');
```

Comment: Can you check if your routes use the `web` middleware group? You can run `php artisan route:list` and check the middle column. Your routes should use `web` middleware group for sessions to work.

Answer (score 0):

The form method must be "POST" ,you can use {{ method_field('PUT') }} to set the method

Comment: Thank you for you recommend but i got still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

in Your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`  put the following code in `render` function

```
//instance of Token Mismatched
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){
        //redirect to a form. Here is an example of how I handle mine
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('csrf_error', $exception->getMessage());
    }
```

at top use the following line :

```
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
```

Comment: Thank you for you recommend but i got still the same problem